# Having a listbox call the ToString method for all of its items

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list box that contains a set of of PathItems. I have overridden the ToString method with a couple different cases depending on the user's preferences.

It is basically a list of file names contained in custom objects.

```
class PathItem
{
    public static bool show_ext { get; set; }
    public static bool use_full_path { get; set; }
    public string filepath { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (use_full_path)
            return filepath;
        else if (show_ext)
            return Path.GetFileName(filepath);
        else
            return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath);
    }
}
```

The GUI has two checkboxes. One checkbox will show file extensions, another checkbox will  show the absolute path of the file. Checking any of these will update the static variables defined above.

Whenever I select a checkbox, I would like the listbox to be updated to reflect the user's selection.

I believe the solution is to have the listbox refresh all of its items by calling the ToString method again to get new values for each item, but I'm not sure how this would be done.

Also I am not sure if this is true, but if I said

```
PathItem.show_ext = true;
```

would this apply to all existing `PathItem` objects?

UPDATE:

After trying the `Refresh` method as suggested, the strings in the list box weren't updated even when the checkboxes were checked (they fire off a Refresh call on ClickChanged). Wrote a print statement inside the `ToString` method, but upon refreshing, no message was printed out.

Not sure if this is because I am using custom objects in my list box.

This is how I'm adding items to my list box

```
foreach (string filename in files)
    listBox1.Items.Add(new PathItem { filepath = filename });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly, calling

```
myListBox.Refresh()
```

does *not* cause the ListBox re-evaluate ToString() on the contained objects.  Presumably the values are cached somewhere.

You can use the following method to force a ListBox to re-evaluate ToString().  I tested it with >100 items in my ListBox (on a fast computer) and saw no visual artifacts or delay.

```
    private void UpdateToString(ListBox listBox)
    {
        int count = listBox.Items.Count;
        listBox.SuspendLayout();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            listBox.Items[i] = listBox.Items[i];
        }
        listBox.ResumeLayout();
    }
```

Also,

```
PathItem.show_ext = true;
```

would immediately affect every PathItem instance that references *show_ext* from that point forward, because *show_ext* is a static variable.  It only has one value at any point in time, which is shared between all instances of that class.

Comment: I was thinking `Refresh` would do the trick, but now that I've added in some print statements into my custom `ToString` method, it actually isn't being called when I refresh the listbox. I wonder if it's because I have those custom `PathItem` objects in my listbox's items.

Comment: Give me a moment to look into this.

Comment: Updated my answer with a tested solution.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what controls are actually doing when they refresh themselves. But the solution looks like it shouldn't have any odd side-effects, so I'll go with that for now.

Comment: I suspect that ListBox is caching the result of ToString() to speed up display of individual rows.

Comment: It's not "caching" them, it's calling `ToString` on each of the objects and passing the result to the native Win32 ListBox control when the item(s) is inserted. I guess you could say that it is caching the values. But the reason that `Refresh` doesn't work is that it doesn't delete and refill the Win32 control wrapped by WinForms. You have to do that manually, as you've done here.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for it for *ComboBox*, but it could work for *ListBox* as well: force the control to recreate it's handle, and if that fail just change the *DrawMode* to something else and change it back.

Lets make it as extensive method so you can call it from everywhere easily:

```
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="ListBox"/> helper methods
/// </summary>
public static class ListBoxHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Forces the control to refresh it's items drawing
    /// </summary>
    public static void Redraw(this ListBox control)
    {
        // Check input parameter
        if (control != null)
        {
            // Try get handle recreate method, may fail in some scenarios
            MethodInfo recreate = typeof(Control).GetMethod("RecreateHandle", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (recreate != null)
            {
                // Just force control do recreate it's handle
                recreate.Invoke(control, null);
            }

            // Fail to get recreate handle method
            // Let's do it manually
            else
            {
                // Render is normal?
                DrawMode original = control.DrawMode;
                if (original == DrawMode.Normal)
                {
                    // Change it to owner and then back in normal
                    control.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
                    control.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Change it to normal and them back to original
                    control.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal;
                    control.DrawMode = original;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to use it just:

```
this.MyList.Redraw();
```